Comedy about a group being caught by a tribe of women and forced to mate
My memory is vague on this movie. But this is what I can remember:
The movie is in color.
Think it is pre 80s or early 80s
A group of travelers are captured by a tribe of women (I think the tribe is unable to have male children). They then force the males in the group to have sex with the women. The females in the group (maybe wives of the males) get upset with how much the guys are enjoying it and then either take charge or influence the tribe to only give the guys ugly women. I can't remember how it ends.

I'm pretty sure you're on about Carry on up the Jungle (1970).
This follows the search for Joan Sims' husband who had gone missing.  As you remember, they end up with a tribe of women who are unable to have male heirs and put the men in the party "to work". But Sims' character makes sure that their mates are husky, as you can see in the trailer around 2:25:



